# Loop through a list with an index in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a data frame, within the data frame I hold the temperature values. I want to calculate the average temperature within an interval. Therefore, I have a first_temp variable, when I add its index number to the time difference value, I should go to last_tempeture.
But when I add two indexes, I could get higher values than the total length of the data frame, and this can cause an error.

Now, I am working on the following code and I get  "The true value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" error.

I hope you could help me to fix this problem.

```
average_temp=[]
for i in result.index:
first_temp=result["temp"][i]
ind=result["Time Difference"][i]
j=i+ind
j=int(j)
lst = list(range(i,j))


for x in last:
    ind_max=max(last)
    if (ind_max<result.index):
        last_temp+=result["temp"][x]     
        average=last_temp/x
        average_temp.append(average)
```

Comment: Hi apulo, when you encounter an error, usually your Python will show you which line of code that raise the particular error you mention. It will be easier for use to debug if you can point out which line that raise the error

Comment: btw have you seen the pandas diff() method ? it is useful to calculate the difference of values with previous time step. Maybe you can use it to solve your problem. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html

Comment: @VinsonCiawandy, the error occurs in if condition line. I will also check the diff method, thank you.

Comment: I think, i am about to solve it, I guess, I was giving an array to the if condition, and therefore It created an error, now i changed it, like this,    ind_max=max(lst)
        if (ind_max<len(result)): , it miscalculates the result for now, but I am getting closer